# Rendering error page in LiveView after async task returns error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

Is there a better way to make this work?

I want do some asynchronous work in a Task in LiveView. If the result is an error condition, I want to show an error page to the end user instead of the main LiveView page. Here is what I am currently doing:

1. Call an async Task to do some work via Task.Supervisor.async_nolink/3 in handle_params/3
2. Use handle_info/2 to listen for the result. If the result is an error, I redirect to the root page "/" using Phoenix.LiveView.redirect/2
3. I have an if statement in handle_param/2 that says:

   ```
   if result_of_async_workflow == :error do
     raise UnknownErrorPage
   end
   ```

This displays the correct error page to the user.

Is the only way to accomplish this workflow? I tried `raise UnknownErrorPage` in handle_info/2, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try with this, this is a handle event function that invokes an anonymous function that redirect to another page

```
 def handle_event("do_task", %{"id" => id}, socket) do
    Task.async(fn -> async_task(id) end)

    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  defp async_task(id) do

    {:ok, redirect(socket, to: "/otra_pagina")}
  end
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**